# PLATO BRONCE ESCUDO HISPAN TE IND REX NG 8R P

Tags: meaning

Does "Hispan te Ind Rex NG 8R P" mean something like "King of Spain and the Indies"? What would be a more accurate translation? Thank you!

"[PLATO BRONCE ESCUDO HISPAN TE IND REX NG 8R P](https://en.todocoleccion.net/military-replicas-reproductions/placa-medallon-bronce-hispan-te-ind-rex-ng-8r-p%7Ex269848793)"

Comment: I'm not positive, but the "te" seems like a typo, which would be hilarious on a replica piece. There are a lot more Google hits for "HISPAN ET IND"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would seem to be a typo. The correct inscription would be:

> HISPAN[IARUM] ET IND[IARUM] REX
> *King of Spain and the Indies*
> N[UEVA] G[RANADA] 8 R[EALES] P
> *New Granada, 8 Real, P*

I'm not sure what the P stands for. (Maybe it stands for one *peso*, which is worth eight *real*?) But HISPAN ET IND REX is a very standard legend from coins of this era.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer !